# Meaning of Ampersand(&), in .rc files

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, resource-files

When coding Windows Applications using WIN32 on Windows, to non-dynamically load resources, one must load a `*.rc` file, which contains resource definition statements meant for defining common features in apps, such as buttons and menus. While reading a tutorial for the WIN32 API, from [WinProg](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/), I came across this code that confused me:

```
IDR_MYMENU MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "E&xit", ID_FILE_EXIT
    END

    POPUP "&Stuff"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Go", ID_STUFF_GO
        MENUITEM "G&o somewhere else", 0, GRAYED
    END
END
```

Looking at the code above, it is understandable what the function is. I myself understand what the code is doing in the `.rc` file, but the one thing that confused me was the ampersands,(`&`), that are visible in the middle of the strings, such as `"G&o somewhere else"` (Between G and O), or `"E&xit"` (Between E and X). My specific questions to Stack Overflow are: What do the ampersands mean in the `.rc` files? Where do I have to put them when coding apps? I already looked in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link describing the function of the files, but I couldn't get an answer in the docs.

Comment: That is the key for the shortcut.

Comment: Could you explain what that means, exactly, as in what is a key for a shortcut, and why is the `&` specifically there?

Comment: You know when you see one of the letters that are underlined in the menu item when you run the program?  That is the shortcut key.  The `&` is there because it is the way to tell Windows (for example) "underline the 'x' for me when you display `Exit` in the menu and use it as a shortcut".

Comment: The term used by Microsoft is [either "menu access key" or "mnemonic"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Menu_Access_Keys).

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks guys, could one of you add that as an answer, I'll mark it correct, for other user's future reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those `&`s are only for menus, and they define the ["menu access keys", or "mnemonics"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647553(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Menu_Access_Keys), also called accelerators and shortcuts by others. And yes, the terminology is overloaded and confusing.

More reading: [why you probably didn't realize these were there](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061005-00/?p=29463).

Comment: Besides menus, the `&` also works as a `mnemonic character` in controls that have a label ([Common Control Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380902.aspx)). For example a button defined with `&Save` in a dialog template will display as `S̲ave` (after pressing `ALT`) and respond to `ALT+S`.